# Python Plotly multicolored line plot by Z values

Tags: python, plotly

Given a dataframe `df` with columns `X,Y,Z`, generating the xz plot with plotly is relatively easy:

```
    px.line(df, x='X', y='Y',).write_image("path.png")
```

The question is - how can I color encode it in, for example, grey-red colorcoding, where grey represents low values, and red high values, by the values stored in `Z`?
[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIasb.png)

Comment: color=color_continuous_scale=scale       https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/

Comment: Can you please post an answer? color=color_continuous_scale=scale seems like a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Only scatter works with a color scale, but you can set up so many points that it appears to be a line, such as:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000) #1000 points between zero and ten
color=px.colors.sequential.Bluered
fig = px.scatter(x=t, y=np.sin(t), labels={'x':'t', 'y':'sin(t)'}, color=np.sin(t)) 
fig.show()
```

Comment: Interesting and disappointing. So you are saying I need to sample points from my line and plot them? Thanks

Comment: I think that's the only way to get the color scale in plotly.  I looked at all the documentation that I could find regarding this.